# jquery datatable server side global search is running slow for large datatable

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am using jquery datatable server-side processing in `MVC` using `JSON`.I am able to bind 10 millions of data and pagination is working fine but when I am doing a search it is running slow it is taking `50 secs` I want it in `15 secs` .As it is searching multiple columns it is taking time I have kept `5 columns` on display .I am using `SQL` server as backend and using entity framework6.

controller code

```
MVCEntities1 db = new MVCEntities1();

                IObjectContextAdapter dbcontextadapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)db;
                dbcontextadapter.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;


                int pageNo = 1;
                if(param.iDisplayStart >= param.iDisplayLength)
                {

                    pageNo = (param.iDisplayStart / param.iDisplayLength) + 1;
                }

                if (param.sSearch!=null)
                {

                    var result = (from r in db.MyTable
                                  where ( (r.CompanyName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                                  || r.City.Contains(param.sSearch) || r.Website.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                                  r.Contact_Name.Contains(param.sSearch) ))
                                  orderby r.id
                                  select new { r.CompanyName, r.Website, r.ContactName, r.Country, r.City, r.Phone_Number }).
                                      Skip((pageNo - 1) * param.iDisplayLength).Take(param.iDisplayLength);


                    var resultcount = (from r in db.MyTable
                                       where ((r.Company_Name.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                                       r.City.Contains(param.sSearch) || r.Website.Contains(param.sSearch) ||
                                       r.Contact_Name.Contains(param.sSearch) 
                                       ))
                                       select r).Count();


                    JsonResult result2 = Json(new
                    {

                        aaData = result,
                        sEcho = param.sEcho,
                        iTotalDisplayRecords = resultcount,
                        iTotalRecords = resultcount
                    }
                       , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                    result2.MaxJsonLength = 8675309;
                    return result2;

                }

    Index view  code :

     var BindDataTable = function (response) {
                $.noConflict();
       var tbl= $("#EmpInfo").DataTable({

           "bServerSide": true,

                    "sAjaxSource": "/Main/CustomerList",
                    "Processing": true,
                    "deferRender": true,
                    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                        var countryname = $('#Country').val();
                        aoData.push(
                  { "name": "Id", "value": countryname }

                  );
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: sSource,
                            data: aoData,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: fnCallback
                        })

                    },
                    "aoColumns": [

                                       { "mData": "CompanyName" },
                                       { "mData": "Website" },
                                       { "mData": "ContactName" },
                                       { "mData": "Country" },
                                       { "mData": "City" },
                                       { "mData": "PhoneNumber" }

                    ]




       });

       <div class="form-horizontal">
        <table id="EmpInfo" width="90%" align="center" class="table table-bordered  table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="button" onclick="closetable()" value="close x" id="closetable" /></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Website</th>
                    <th>Contact Name</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```